# how to make a cell populate data from another sheet based on dropdown selection

Tags: excel, drop-down-menu, vlookup, populate

I've looked and didn't get an example that works for my situation.

I am making a pricing calculator and need to have pricing populate in cells once I've selected the device from a dropdown.

I've created the source data in Sheet2 Column A is Device Column B is MSRP and Column C is Discounted price

On Sheet 1 I want to select a device in cell B4 (already have that dropdown created) and have it automatically populate the MSRP in C4 and the Discounted price in D4.

I'm not very familiar with how to use Vlookup and IFERROR and the other answers I've seen didn't explain how the formulas worked enough for me to adapt those to my situation.

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

=IFERROR(VLOOKUP (B4,'Sheet2'!A$1:C$200,2,FALSE)),"-")

In C4 in sheet 1 will return the value from column 2 on the range A:C in sheet 2 (i.e column B). Change the 2 to 3 in D4 to get the value from column C in sheet 2. The FALSE forces excel to match the values exactly rather than just picking the first likely match it finds. If it can't find the value IFERROR returns -. You can change C$200 to cover the full range of whatever is in your list in sheet 2.